# Why the `nounset` shell option doesn't raise an error on unset arrays?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

Why no errors are raised when `unset` is set, and an undefined array is referenced?

Am i missing something, e.g. this is controlled by another option?

Example:

```sh
set -o nounset

echo "${foo[*]}" # no error
echo "${foo[@]}" # no error

echo "$foo" # error
```

I've checked [the manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html), but I'm puzzled, because it mentions `$@` and `$*`, but not arrays:

> Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters ‘@’ or ‘*’ as an error

The Bash version I'm using is 5.0.

Comment: Earlier versions behaved as you expected, however that was inconsistent with **$@** and **$\*** and was fixed in 4.4-rc2. See [the release notes](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-08/msg00123.html) for the first version where the behavior has changed, under *New Features in Bash* it says *Using ${a[@]} or ${a[\*]} with an array without any assigned elements 
when the nounset option is enabled no longer throws an unbound variable error.*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is just a shortcoming of the documentation; it should mention array parameters index with `@` and `*` as well.

The intent is to make it look like an array can be "set" to an empty value. However,

```
foo=()
```

doesn't actually assign an empty array value to the name `foo`. It simply sets the array attribute on the *name* `foo`, and clears any values that may already have been present. `$foo` and `${foo[0]}` are equivalent, and both will be treated as an unset parameter. Each of `${foo[@]}` and `${foo[@]}` are special cased to be "set", but "empty", as far as `-u` is concerned.

Note, though, that the array attribute doesn't actually need to be set for the `@`/`*` indices to override `-u`.

```
$ unset bar
$ set -o nounset
$ echo ${bar[@]}

$
```